# Creating a custom Dialog screen with progress bar in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a custom Dialog box with Black background on all screen and a spinner in middle.

Here is my code

```
public class ActivityIndicator extends Dialog
{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private CountDownTimer timer = null;

    public ActivityIndicator(Context context) 
    {
       super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_indicator);
        this.setCancelable(false);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(200);
      }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) 
        {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {
                 progressBar.setProgress((int) millisUntilFinished/10);
             }

             public void onFinish() 
             {

                timer.cancel();
                timer.start();
             }
          };
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss()
    {
        timer.cancel();
    }


}
```

and XML Is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:alpha="0.6" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my MainActivity

```
 mDialog = new ActivityIndicator(this);
        mDialog.show();
```

Now after this. the onShow() is called but nothing happens.

What do i need to do to add the whole screen dialog to show on screen. Nothing is showing up on my Main Activity screen. Like it add the standard view of dialog box.

[image]

Comment: Nothing is happening, the dialog is not adding the view on my Activity.

Comment: you override show but you missed to call super.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to call `super.show();` in the override method of you custom dialog. To remove the dialog's background, you have to pass as second argument a transparent theme to your dialog instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TransparentDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>

mDialog = new ActivityIndicator(this, R.style.TransparentDialog);
```

Comment: one small issue. Now its working but in layout i have a relative layout and a progress bar. Its working fine. but it is wrapped by a square view which is gray in color. How can i make this square disappear. It appears in middle of screen and inside it, is my progress bar. (I have removed black background and alpha of relativeLayout)

Comment: could you post a screenshot?

Comment: yes i have tried , in my xml even i have removed the relative layout and using only progress bar but still this is showing